# Java Gson JsonSyntaxException caused by ParseException: Unparsable date

Tags: java, json, date, serialization, gson

I know there is a **lot of questions related to this problem on StackOverflow** (**I have tried a lot of solutions for them**), but I have been **trying for hours** to fix this problem and I always get the **same error**.
I have ***list of dates in JSON***, and when I try to deserialize it, I get following error: 

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2020-08-30` 
`Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020-08-30" at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:396) at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:79)`.

***My code:*** 
Gson:

```
private static Gson g = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .serializeNulls()
            .create();
```

Field in Java class:

```
private List<Date> freeDates;
```

Part of JSON for that field:

```
{"freeDates": ["2020-08-30", "2020-08-31", "2020-09-01", "2020-09-02"]}
```

I have also tried other date formats, like ISO-8601 standard, but the result is always the same... 
Sorry for repeating question. 
Thanks in advance!

***UPDATE:*** Part of code where I call `fromJson` method. This is my GenericRepository class, all Repository classes extend this class.

```
public List<T> getAllEntities(String fileName){
        BufferedReader br = null;
        List<T> entities = new ArrayList<T>();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line;
            StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
            
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                fileContent.append(line);
                if(line.trim().equals("END")) {
                    fileContent.delete(fileContent.length() - 4, fileContent.length());
                    T entity = g.fromJson(fileContent.toString(), type);
                    entities.add(entity);
                    fileContent.setLength(0);
                }else
                    fileContent.append("\n");       
            }
            
            return entities;
            
        }
```

Comment: Could you please add a piece of code, where do you call fromJson method?

Comment: **Unable to reproduce.** Works fine when I test it with `gson-2.8.5.jar`

Comment: @AlexanderMakarov @AlexanderMakarov I have GenericRepository class so all Repository classes extend it. `fromJson` method is in that class. I have updated my question with code where I call that method.

Answer (score 0):

Your Json string has to have curly braces:

```
String json = "{\"freeDates\": [\"2020-08-30\", \"2020-08-31\", \"2020-09-01\", \"2020-09-02\"]}";
Object converted = g.fromJson(json, Object.class);
System.out.println(converted);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I know, JSON is in correct form and I have curly braces. This was just part of JSON for `private List<Date> freeDates;` field in class.